# How can i add headers in Qtableview

Tags: python, pyside

Here is my code,i create a table format by using table view.It consist of 4 columns for that columns i want to add header names like filename, size,and date of modified,but i don't want to add any names to my buttons.so can you please guide me how can i add header names to only for file,date and date modified in my table view
Given bellow is my code:

```
import sys
import os
import csv
import datetime
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class ViewWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    dirPath = "C:\raghava\main project"
    def __init__(self, x, index, parent=None):
        super(ViewWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.p_index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index)
        self.content_button = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        lay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.content_button)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0,0)
        self.label = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.label.setText(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
        self.label.setReadOnly(True)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.label1.setText(self.dirPath)
        self.label1.setReadOnly(True)
        self.label1.resize(250, 100)
        self.label1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)
        lay.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.content_button.move(x, 0)  

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.dirPath = ViewWidget.dirPath
        self.open_file()
        self.file_data=""
    def open_file(self):
        self.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QWidget())
        layout = QtGui. QGridLayout(self.centralWidget())
        self.model  =QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView()
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableView.clicked.connect(self.onClick)

        self.tableView.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.appendRowItems(self.dirPath)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.resize(1300,500)
    def appendRowItems(self, dir_path):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
            if root == dir_path:
                for file in files:
                    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(file)
                    item.setData(os.path.join(root, file))
                    self.model.appendRow(item)
                    ix = self.model.indexFromItem(item)
                    self.tableView.setIndexWidget(ix, ViewWidget(1270, ix))
    @QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def onClick(self, ix):
        pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    eg =  Example()
    vw= ViewWidget(1270,QtGui.QStandardItemModel().indexFromItem(QtGui.QStandardItem("./adding_buttons.py")))
    eg.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it is better to have several columns and set the buttons in the last column:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class ViewWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, index, parent=None):
        super(ViewWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.p_index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index)

        self.content_button = QtGui.QWidget(self)

        self.view_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("View")
        self.share_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Share", clicked=self.share_clicked)
        self.delete_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Delete", clicked=self.delete_clicked)

        lay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.content_button)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0,0)
        lay.addWidget(self.view_btn)
        lay.addWidget(self.share_btn)
        lay.addWidget(self.delete_btn)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def delete_clicked(self):
        model = self.p_index.model()
        model.removeRow(self.p_index.row())

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def share_clicked(self):
        model = self.p_index.model()
        name = model.index(self.p_index.row(), 0).data()
        print(name)

class DirView(QtGui.QTableView):
    lengthChanged = QtCore.Signal(int)
    def __init__(self, directory="", parent=None):
        super(DirView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setShowGrid(False)

        self._model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self._model.setColumnCount(4)
        labels = ("filename", "size", "date", "")
        self._model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)
        self.setModel(self._model)
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        if directory:
            self.load(directory)

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    @QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QDir)
    def load(self, path):
        directory = QtCore.QDir(path)
        for i, finfo in enumerate(directory.entryInfoList(QtCore.QDir.Files)):
            filename =   finfo.fileName()
            size = finfo.size()
            lastModified = finfo.lastModified().toString()

            it_name = QtGui.QStandardItem(finfo.fileName())
            it_size = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(finfo.size()))
            it_last_modified = QtGui.QStandardItem(finfo.lastModified().toString())
            it_buttons = QtGui.QStandardItem()

            for j, it in enumerate((it_name, it_size, it_last_modified, it_buttons)):
                self._model.setItem(i, j, it)

            ix = self._model.indexFromItem(it_buttons)
            buttons = ViewWidget(ix)
            self.setIndexWidget(ix, buttons)


class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.open_file()

    def open_file(self):
        self.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QWidget())
        view = DirView()
        dirPath = r"C:\raghava\main project"
        view.load(dirPath)

        layout = QtGui. QGridLayout(self.centralWidget())
        layout.addWidget(view)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    eg =  Example()
    eg.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```